# How make Android multiple layouts work as expected

Tags: android-layout

Hi everyone I am using eclipse to develop an android app. I have three layouts, namely a main layout and two other layouts linked to the main layout. I have created .xml and .java files for all the pages. My application runs and I can move between my main layout and one of the layouts but when I try to access the other layout the screen just blinks and nothing else happens. I am using bluestacks to test the app. below is the code for the button that is supposed to execute and move between the layouts. Show_Meds.class is the problematic one. What am I doing wrong?

```
`Button butEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
 butEnter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
  if ( rEnterMed.isChecked()){
     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,  Enter_Meds.class));
  }
  else if (rShowMed.isChecked()){
     startActivity(new Intent   (MainActivity.this, Show_Meds.class));
  }

   }//end of onClick
});`
```

Comment: Use physical device(android phone) for debugging, bluestack :( and post all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer for you yet, But please verify these points to find out whats going wrong.

Also, if you are unable to produce favourable results, please post the codes for all your layout.xml files, your manifest files and your Activity.java files.

1- Make sure you have registered your Activities `Enter_Meds` and `Show_Meds` to your manifest files.

2- Try replacing the layouts xml file of MainActivity to `Enter_Meds` and `Show_Meds` one by one in `setContentView`. This way, you'll know if the xml  view are actually working OK.

3- Inside `onClick` method, print out the value of `v.getId()` to verify if the view has been clicked correctly.